# Computer running extremely slow on 19.04, any suggestions?

Tags: 19.04

Computer running verrry slow.. How may this be rectified? (19.04)

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                           
2880 root      20   0  262020  43240  34580 R  60.0   1.1  16:05.41 Xorg                                                                              
4034 sayne     20   0 3567880 147212  52868 S  40.0   3.8   3:40.92 gnome-shell                                                                       
3913 sayne     20   0  338420   6000   3168 S  20.0   0.2   0:00.92 ibus-extension-                                                                   
5630 sayne     20   0  976408  44224  32576 S  20.0   1.1   0:00.87 gnome-terminal-                                                                   
5709 sayne     20   0   12052   3752   3064 R  20.0   0.1   0:00.07 top
```

Comment: What are your specs?

Comment: How do I get those up to show u?